# how to increase a mathematical function by matlab

Tags: matlab, function, compare

I have a function f(x,y) with two real variables x and y, is i want to increase it for all x and y, that's possible, i.e:

Find two real a and b such that the norm of f(x, y) will be increased by: a times the norm of x + b times the norm of y.
kindly, I'm looking for a Matlab function that gives me a and b, thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This sounds an awful lot like a homework assignment.

Comment: yes thanks, it's an awful lot question, I tried with functions as: all, find and exist but I do not get results.